# In generic method, why the generic overload is preferred to an implemented method with parent type?

Tags: c#, overloading, c#-5.0, generic-method

Let's say I create a generic method, and implement some types, like shown in the code below.
I also have two objects, a `Foo` and a `Bar`, where `Bar` inherits from `Foo`.

I then implement the generic method for `Foo`.

If I call the method with `Bar`, why doesn't it hit the `Foo` overload of the method?

I tested the code below and that's what it returns. I am more interested in why that happens.

My question raises because I want to process `Bet` and `Bar` the same way, so the body of the method would be the same. Although, I cannot see how to do this without either duplicating the code, or creating another method that dispatches to the correct one.

```
public class Foo 
{
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
}

public class Bet : Foo
{
}

public static void Test(Foo foos)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You hit Test(Foo)");
}

public static void Test<T>(T generic)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You hit Test<T>");
}

void Main()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    Bet bet = new Bet();
    
    Test(foo);  // Prints "You hit Test(Foo)", as expected 
    Test(bar);  // Prints "You hit Test<T>", I expexted "You hit Test(Foo)"
    Test(bet);  // Prints "You hit Test<T>", I expexted "You hit Test(Foo)"
}
```

Comment: Because the generic method creates a new method with the *exact* type, so it's a better match than the method with the parent type

Comment: Why would it hit `List<object>`? `List<object>` and `List<int>` aren't compatible. Try `List<object> a = new List<int>();` to see what I mean.

Comment: Indeed, using `int` and `object` is a bad example. `object` is *not* the parent type of `int`. Even if it were, `List<object>` is not the parent type of `List<int>`, it's a different type entirely

Comment: An example that actually demonstrates the question would be two methods that accept types A and B, with B inheriting from A: `Test<T>(T generic)` and `Test(A a)`. Even then, the generic method will be picked because it matches the type exactly.

Comment: Thanks guys, apologies for the misleading code - I amended that to match the question

Answer (score 3):

The code doesn't match the question. First of all, `object` is not the parent of `int`. Value types have to be boxed to be converted to `object`. Even with reference types, assuming A is the parent of B, `List<A>` is *not* the parent of `List<B>`. `List<A>` creates a new type that has no inheritance relation to `List<B>`.

An example that actually demonstrates the question would be :

```
class A    {    }

class B:A  {    }

static string Test<T>(T generic)
{
    Console.WriteLine("T - generic overload");
    return "Generic overload";
}

static string Test(A a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A - A overload");
    return "A overload";
}

static string Test(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("object - objectoverload");
    return "object overload";
}


void Main()
{
    var b =new B() ;
    var a=new A() ;

    Test(b);
    Test(a);
}
```

The output would be :

```
T - generic overload
A - A overload
```

The generic overload creates an exact match for `B` which means it's a better fit than `Test(A)`